# Internet connection slowing down till stop

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 as second OS on my PC and I'm having a strange issue.

When I try to connect to internet I notice a progressive slowing in the network speed till it completely stuck.

Then to restart connection I need to reboot my router (it's a D-Link DSL 2542b), but the problem repeats after a while...

This is never happened using Windows, so I don't know if it can depend on Ubuntu or it's a problem of my router.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this might be due to some software update happening in the instance. Please check this by changing the package update settings to manual. Also install bandwidth monitoring tool and check whether any process is consuming the bandwidth for process like back ground sync